# How can I create an old school table in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to create a table like the expected result.
Here is my code:

```js
import "./CalendarTable.css";
export default function CalendarTable() {

    return (
        <div className="calendarTableContainer">
            <table className="calendarTable">
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
.calendarTable {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    height: 50%;
}

.calendarTableContainer {
    margin: 3px;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

Although I have set the border-collapse: separate, the output still does not change.

Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result:

[image]

The following HTML code can produce what I need.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" height="50%" width="50%">
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with react - if you strip out react and just do that as HTML/css you get the same result.

Comment: "height: 50%", 50% of what? You need to set a height for the table,

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting the old-school `border` value on a `table` yields the result you want.

```js
function CalendarTable() {
    return (
            <table border={1}>
                <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
                <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
            </table>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<CalendarTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you don't want to use that, then you'll need to emulate the similar styles with inset and outset borders.

```js
function CalendarTable() {
    return (
            <table>
                <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
                <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
            </table>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<CalendarTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px outset grey;
}
table td {
  border: 1px inset grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things, your `.calendarTableContainer` doesn't have any height, and you want to add
a border to the `td` im assuming.

So to fix this, I added a simply hieght of `500px` to`.calendarTableContainer` (for example purposes)

then added this to the CSS

```
.calendarTable td {
    border: 1px inset black;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
.calendarTable {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    height: 50%;
}

.calendarTableContainer {
    margin: 3px;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: 500px;
}

.calendarTable td {
    border: 1px inset black;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarTableContainer">
            <table class="calendarTable">
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: OP's screenshot has inset/outset borders, not solid black ones.

Comment: @AKX easy enough fix, I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `inset black` is still black.

Comment: @AKX yeah and what's the problem with that? My output is literally identical to his "expected" outcome screenshot.

Comment: But it literally isn't identical. OP's output has multiple shades of gray in the borders, yours doesn't.

Comment: bro, yeah mine does... https://i.imgur.com/Wpt1ZHz.jpeg

Comment: Not on my machine, it doesn't. https://i.stack.imgur.com/htnni.png Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define height of parent so 50% doesn't know what it should refer to. Analyze the code below. It creates what you want

```css
.calendarTableContainer {
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height:100vh;
}

.calendarTable {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    height: 50%;
}

td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```